# Combine Rails 3 scope into class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have 4 Rails 3 scopes that I would like to simplify:

```
  scope :age_0, lambda {
    where("available_at IS NULL OR available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days)
  }
  scope :age_30, lambda {
    where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days, Date.today + 60.days)
  }
  scope :age_60, lambda {
    where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 60.days, Date.today + 90.days)
  }
  scope :age_90, lambda {
    where("available_at >= ?", Date.today + 90.days)
  }
```

I thought about a class method:

```
def self.aging(days)

  joins(:profile).where("available_at IS NULL OR available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days) if days==0
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days, Date.today + 60.days) if days==30
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 60.days, Date.today + 90.days) if days==60
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ?", Date.today + 90.days) if days==90

end
```

But I don't know what to return to ensure that it will be compatible with Rails 3 scopes.

Is this a good approach?  Is there a better way to do this?

** edit **
I updated the method's logic.  The if test doesn't seem to work as I expect.

Comment: Cool idea.  What's the goal?  what would self.aging return?

Comment: some sort of filter.  joins(:profile).where("available_at > ?", Date.today + 90.days)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need a 'default' action.  I added 'joins(:profile)'.  Perhaps there is a better way, but this worked.

```
def self.aging(days)

  joins(:profile).where("available_at IS NULL OR available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days) if days==0
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 30.days, Date.today + 60.days) if days==30
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", Date.today + 60.days, Date.today + 90.days) if days==60
  joins(:profile).where("available_at >= ?", Date.today + 90.days) if days==90
  joins(:profile)

end
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass an argument to the lambda?

```
scope :available_range, lambda { |start|
    where("available_at >= ? AND available_at < ?", start, end+30.days)
}
```

Also, see "Dynamic Scope Construction" here: http://archives.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html